# How to find MLE from a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I'm new to probability. Given the cumulative distribution function $f_Y(y)=\theta e^{-y\theta}$ defined from 0 to infinity, I would like to find the parameter $\theta$ such that it maximizes the likelihood function. I first thought that since PDF and CDF are strictly correlated between each other, I tried finding the first derivative of the CDF with respect to $\theta$: 
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\theta e^{-y\theta})=0 \implies \theta=\frac{1}{y}$$

Then I tried solving the PDF form the CDF:
$$\frac{d}{dy}(\theta e^{-y\theta})=-\theta^2e^{-y\theta}$$
Which gives me the likelihood function for the continuous distribution. Naturally, I calculated the derivative with respect to $\theta$ of the likelihood function:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(-\theta^2e^{-y\theta})=0 \implies \theta=0 \vee \frac{2}{y}$$

My question is: why do I get two different values for $\theta$ with the two different approaches?

The textbook also suggests that for the sample $Y_1, ..., Y_n$, the MLE is $1/{\bar{Y_n}}$, which still is different from the two results I found. Can someone help me make some clarifications?

Comment: $f_Y$ is a PDF for $y>0$, not CDF.

Comment: Thanks, how can we deduce that it is the former and not the latter?

Comment: In general: First you have to set up the likelihood function (!!!) which is based on a sample with a sample size of $n$

Comment: @Kevin By properties of PDF/CDF.

Comment: PDF integrates to 1 over the domain it is define. So that's a quick check whether a function is a pdf or not.

Comment: @Kevin "Thanks, how can we deduce that it is the former and not the latter?" CDFs increase, finally reaching $1$. Calculus easily shows $\theta e^{-y\theta}$ falls once $y>1/\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MLE estimator is the value of parameter, in your case of $\theta$, that maximizes the likelihood of observing a SAMPLE of observations, $\{Y_1,...,Y_N\}$. To compute MLE estimator you then need to set up a likelihood function. If the sample observations are *i.i.d.* then the likelihood function is given by the product of densities of each observation conditional on $\theta$.

---

In your case, the likelihood function is
$$ L = \prod_{i=1}^N \theta e^{-\theta y_i}$$

Maximizing this function w.r.t $\theta$ yields solution

$$ \theta = \frac{N}{\sum_i^N y_i} = \frac{1}{\overline{y}_n},$$

where $\overline{y}_n = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N y_i$.

Notice that this solution agrees with your solution (proposed at the beginning of your post) when you have only one observation, namely $N=1$. In that case, MLE estimate is simply $1/y_1$.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was extremely helpful for me :)